# Retrieve the words after the last numeric occurrence using regex

Tags: regex

I receive `streetname + doorno` in a string variable. I have to split them. My current regex is `/[0-9].*$/`  This works fine for normal addresses. But I have addresses where `streetname` also contains a numeric value. In this case, the `streetname` is considered as `doorno` too.

For ex,

```
[Correct] Street = Example Street 15B returns doorno = 15B

[Correct] Street = Example Street 15 B returns doorno = 15 B

[Correct] Street = Example Street returns doorno = null

[Correct] Street = Example Street15 returns doorno = 15

[Incorrect] Street = Example Street 158 7 returns doorno = 158 7. However I am expecting, the streetname = Example Street 158 & doorno = 7

[Incorrect] Street = Example Street 158 7 B returns doorno = 158 7 B. However I am expecting, the streetname = Example Street 158 & doorno = 7 B

[Incorrect] Street = Example Street 158 7B returns doorno = 158 7B. However I am expecting, the streetname = Example Street 158 & doorno = 7B

[Incorrect] Street = Example Street158 7 B returns doorno = 158 7B. However I am expecting, the streetname = Example Street158 & doorno = 7B
```

Can someone please help me to fix the regex for the above incorrect cases?

Comment: Try `/^(.*\D)(\d.*)$/`

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
/^(.*\D)(\d.*)$/
```

It matches:

- `^` - start of a string
- `(.*\D)` - Group 1: any 0+ chars  (other than line break chars) up to the last occurrence of the subsequent subpatterns (ie. `\D\d.*$`)
- `(\d.*)` - Group 2: a digit and then any 0+ chars (other than line break chars)
- `$` - end of string.